# Java Method Security Interceptor without adding Annotations to single Methods

Tags: java, spring-security

i've tried in various ways to replicate the `@PreAuthorize` behaviour, so spel expression with a Method Invocation context:
-I started with configuring httpSecurity in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extending class with an access string written in spel, only to figure out the context was on Filter Invocation , so I had no access on the request body(which i need);

-implementing and adding a custom HandlerInterceptor to the InterceptorRegistry, but again the endpoint arguments were not accessible;

-extending ConfigGlobalMethodSecurity to create a custom expressionHandler, but I seems it is only triggered by Method-level annotations;

Can someone explain me if what i've trying to do is simply impossible or is there a way?
I'd like to have the same evaluationContext as @PreAuthorize, so having access the method arguments(I mean the value they assume) using spel expressions and be able to configure it without having to annotate every single class or method.

**EDIT**

for reference these are the two annotations i'm using(and they work fine) the use i'm tring to replicate not by annotations but by configuration:

```java
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE}) 
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(@privilegeManager.privilegedRoles) or (@privilegeManager.verify(#id, this.getType()))")
    public @interface PathVariableRestriction {
    }
```

```java
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(@privilegeManager.privilegedRoles) or #dto.getOwnerId() == @myService.getCurrentId()")
    public @interface RequestBodyRestriction {
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about method level security alternative with spel, but you can achieve this for every endpoint or if you have specific endpoints like /management/** should only be accessed by ADMIN users then, antMatchers with hasRole("ADMIN") and so on

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions

Comment: My issue is i'd like to authorize request not based on roles but on ids: the id of the object being subject to the crud operation provided either as @PathVariable or @RequestBody(depends on if it is a get, post, put or delete) and the id of the current user retrieved through his Authentication

Comment: So you are basically trying to duplicate the Spring Security access control (filtering). Problem with your current all encompassing approach is that you need to know your annotation and the intimate details of it. If you rename your method arguments, or types don't match or ... it won't work.  You could write a security aspect that does all this but you need to find a way to know **where** to trigger that and you probably endup with another annotation or a large list of URLs which you need to maintain.

Comment: Imho a large list of urls in one centralized file is much more mantainable that having annotations scattered in all different controllers annotated method by method, but i guess it's just my way of feeling.

Of course there are limitations in the annotations i'm using at the moment, ie arguments much match the name and types, but again, i find them , although harder to use, simpler to mantain or change, since if i need i only have to change 1 place instead of X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'd like to authorize request not based on roles but on ids: the id of the object being subject to the crud operation provided either as @PathVariable or @RequestBody(depends on if it is a get, post, put or delete) and the id of the current user retrieved through his Authentication

This is one common use case for `@PostAuthorize`.

For example if you do:

```java
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.username == authentication.name")
@GetMapping("/resource/{id}")
public MyResource getResource(String id) {
    // look up
    return myResource;
}
```

This will only return resources that belong to the currently authenticated user.

This is the recommended route.

> able to configure it without having to annotate every single class or method

Alternatively, you can build your own custom authorization method security from scratch using Spring Security's underlying components.

Method Security is built on top of Spring AOP. This means that you can [define your own pointcut](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#jc-method-security-custom-authorization-manager) instead of using Spring Security's annotation-based one. For example, you can do:

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    Advisor myMethodSecurityAdvisor() {
        Pointcut pointcut = myCustomPointcut();
        AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocationResult> rules = myRules();
        AuthorizationManagerAfterMethodInterceptor interceptor = 
            new AuthorizationManagerAfterMethodInterceptor(
                pointcut, rules);
        interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.
            POST_AUTHORIZE.getOrder() + 1);
        return interceptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll give it a try later.
At the moment i've annotated all the methods that needed it with two custom annotations it works as intended, I just find it hard to mantain in an effective manner:

Comment: I know it's been almost a year, but i was able to finally put this advice into practice( albeit only in testing) and this was exactly was I was looking for, so i wanted to thank you again :)

Comment: Sweet! Glad to hear it. Make sure to mark the answer as accepted so that it is clear to folks with the same question that this worked for you.